# Canvas and Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer

I am using Canvas to show Bing Microsoft Map, map was displaying fine until 2 weeks ago. Map is displaying on Chrome, Edge and Firefox and not in IE. I have found the website that is mentioning Canvas is not supporting by IE anymore. Just wondering if anyone having or experiencing the same issue?

Regards

Comment: which version of IE you are using?

Comment: According to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/canvas#Browser_compatibility), IE version 9 supports canvas element in HTML.